# Why are result types of control flow instructions arbitrary? (Especially `return`)

Tags: types, stack, specifications, type-systems, webassembly

I am trying to understand the type system of WebAssembly and confused by control flow instructions. I don't understand **why the result type of `br`, `result` or `unreachable` is an arbitrary type sequence** (t_2^*):

- https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/valid/instructions.html#valid-return
- https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/valid/instructions.html#valid-br
- https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/valid/instructions.html#valid-unreachable

I ran the following two snippets in the [reference interpreter](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter):

```
 (module
   (func (result i32)
     (i32.const 1)
     (i32.const 2)
     (return)
     (return)
   )
 )
```

No type error is reported. However, this one:

```
 (module
   (func (result i32)
     (i32.const 1)
     (i32.const 2)
     (return)
     (f32.const 2)
   )
 )
```

Now I get type error: "test.wast:2.2-7.3: invalid module: type mismatch: operator requires [i32] but stack has [f32]".

But I can try and exploit the "arbitrary type sequence" and write weird programs that are still well-typed:

```
(module
 (func (result i32)
  (i32.const 1)
  (i32.const 2)
  (return)
  (i32.add)
  (i32.add)
  (i32.add)
  (i32.add)
  (i32.add)
  (i32.add)
  (i32.add)
 )
)
```

So what is the point of type checking after the return statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rationale section of the original Wasm design docs contains an [extensive motivation](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Rationale.md#why-polymorphic-stack-typing-after-control-transfer) of this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: In the meantime I found more great discussion of the topic in [a blog post](https://binji.github.io/2017/03/04/webassembly-type-checking.html) and a [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/pull/894).